# Stack data.frames with different columns (after renaming the variables)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have different data.frames with survey data. Each data.frame represents a wave within a longitudinal study. Now I would like to "stack" all the different data.frames so that I have one single data.frame. Unfortunately, sometimes the questions within the questionnaire were changed but the variable name was kept. So, before stacking the data.frames I have to do some checks whether the variables are really the same type of question. E.g. I have to check whether there is the same number of answer categories. Let's create some sample data with three waves (data.frames) :

```r
# Sample Data
###########################################################
n <- 100

df1 <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), size = n, replace = TRUE)),
  var2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = 100, sd = 10),
  var3 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), size = n, replace = TRUE)),
  var4 = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE)
  )

df2 <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), size = n, replace = TRUE)),
  var2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = 100, sd = 10),
  var4 = sample(1:100, size = n, replace = TRUE)
  )

df3 <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), size = n, replace = TRUE)),
  var2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = 100, sd = 10),
  var3 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), size = n, replace = TRUE)),
  var4 = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE)
)
```

In a second step, I am writing a function that creates an overview table for all the variables in all the data.frames:

```r
# Stacking function
###########################################################
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

stackdf <- function(...){
  
  list_of_dfs <- list(...)
  variable_overview <- data.frame(df_no = NA, 
                                  varname = NA, 
                                  class = NA, 
                                  type = NA,
                                  discrete = NA,
                                  fct_levels = NA,
                                  rename_to = NA
                                  )
  df_no <- 1
  
  for (df in list_of_dfs){
    for(var in colnames(df)){
      
      # Check if answer is a factor and count factor levels
      if(is.factor(df[[var]])){
        fct_levels = length(levels(df[[var]]))
      } else{
        fct_levels = NA
      }
      
      # Check if answer is numeric and if it is continuous or discrete
      if(is.numeric(df[[var]])){
        if(length(unique(df[[var]])) > 6){
          discrete = 0
        } else{
          discrete = 1
        }
      } else{
        discrete = NA
      }

      # Add a new entry with type, class etc. for all variables the dfs
      variable_overview <- variable_overview %>% add_row(
              df_no = df_no,
              varname = var,
              class = class(df[[var]]),
              type = typeof(df[[var]]),
              discrete = discrete,
              fct_levels = fct_levels
             )
    }
    
    df_no <- df_no + 1
  }
  
  # Sort by variable and id
  variable_overview <- variable_overview %>% 
    arrange(varname, df_no) %>%
    filter(!is.na(df_no))
  
  print(variable_overview)

  # Renaming the variables
  # (to be done)

  # Stack the data frames
  # stacked_dfs <- plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2, df3)
  # return(stacked_df)
}

stackdf(df1, df2, df3)
```

The result looks like this (see below). For example you can see that between the three waves `var1` differs. In the first wave three different answers could be given, whereas in the second two waves there are only 2 factor levels. Or regarding the variable `var4` in the second wave a continuous scale was used, but a a discrete scale in the first and third wave.

```
   df_no varname   class    type discrete fct_levels rename_to
1      1    var1  factor integer       NA          3        NA
2      2    var1  factor integer       NA          2   var1_W2
3      3    var1  factor integer       NA          2   var1_W2
4      1    var2 numeric  double        0         NA        NA
5      2    var2 numeric  double        0         NA        NA
6      3    var2 numeric  double        0         NA        NA
7      1    var3  factor integer       NA          2        NA
8      3    var3  factor integer       NA          2        NA
9      1    var4 integer integer        1         NA        NA
10     2    var4 integer integer        0         NA   var4_W2
11     3    var4 integer integer        1         NA   var4_W3
```

So, the next step would be to have a variable `rename_to` indicating whether a certain variable needs to be renamed (because the question differs from the question asked in the previous survey (`df_no`). So I need to do pairwise comparisons. For example in the rows 2 and 3 `var1` should be renamed to `var1_W2` because the factor levels have changed from wave 1 to wave 2 (but then again in wave 3 the `var1` should NOT be called `var1_W3` because it's actually the same question as in wave 2). In the rows 10 and 11 the variable names also need to be changed because the question was altered.

But how can I do such pairwise comparisons from top to bottom in my table?
I would also appreciate any comments on how to improve the code.

Comment: Can you show what your expected output would look like?

Comment: Sure, the variable `rename_to` should be as in the table above. In the script I already have that variable is simply set to NA.